# if div does not contain this class then execute following

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

AT the moment I have a few div resize functions that work on different page width queries. These are working fine, however I want to wrap all of these functions for the different window widths in a conditional statement.Basically I only want the functions to resize the div "portfoliopod" if the div does not contain the class pod expanded. Please see my code below and a live example at

http://mrliger.com/index2.php

You can see on the live example that the image is being clipped due to having the height of how the portfoliopod was before expanding it

```
 if ($( '.portfoliopod' ).not( ".podexpanded" )) {




 $(window).resize(function() {
        if ($(window).width() >= 1025) {

var cw = $(".portfoliocontainer").width()/4;
$('.portfoliopod').height(cw);

        } 
    });

$(window).resize(function() {
        if ($(window).width() <= 1024) {

var cw = $(".portfoliocontainer").width()/3;
$('.portfoliopod').height(cw);

        } 
    });

$(window).resize(function() {
        if ($(window).width() <= 767) {

var cw = $(".portfoliocontainer").width()/2;
$('.portfoliopod').height(cw);

        } 
    });

$(window).resize(function() {
        if ($(window).width() <= 400) {

var cw = $(".portfoliocontainer").width();
$('.portfoliopod').height(cw);

        } 
    });

}
```

Comment: You should take a close look at using CSS media queries for different width/height screens. It might make your life a lot easier.

Comment: Your `if` statement will always fired since the selector will return an jquery object, not `false`, `null`, or `undefined`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you do not need multiple `resize` handlers. Include them in the same one.

Second, use the [**:not()**](https://api.jquery.com/not-selector/) selector

```
  $(window).resize(function() {
         if ($(window).width() >= 1025) {
             var cw = $(".portfoliocontainer").width() / 4;
             $('.portfoliopod:not(.podexpanded)').height(cw);
         }
         if ($(window).width() <= 1024) {
             var cw = $(".portfoliocontainer").width() / 3;
             $('.portfoliopod:not(.podexpanded)').height(cw);
         }
         if ($(window).width() <= 767) {
             var cw = $(".portfoliocontainer").width() / 2;
             $('.portfoliopod:not(.podexpanded)').height(cw);
         }
         if ($(window).width() <= 400) {
             var cw = $(".portfoliocontainer").width();
             $('.portfoliopod:not(.podexpanded)').height(cw);
         }
     });
```

Comment: still does not do what I want it to. As per my comment on the previous answer do you think my logic might be wrong here?

Comment: @BenLiger, without more context, it is hard to tell. Can you provide a http://www.fiddle.net and more HTML ?

Comment: @BenLiger, sorry, still not clear. Is this what you wanted? https://jsfiddle.net/z8gLdxoh/5/

Comment: @BenLiger, why exactly does the code in any of the answers not work? That code will only resize divs with out the class podexpanded. What happened when you tried it?

Comment: AmmarCSE, after re-arranging the background images I got it to work but there is now a slight problem with the portfolio container divs height when it reaches certain window widths. The widths it occurs on are from 1025 to 1041 and to 768 to 784. You can see what I mean if you resize your browser window to the above heights on the live page: http://mrliger.com/index2.php

Comment: @BenLiger, sorry, I just got back. Did you resolve your issue?

Comment: not yet but I have asked a new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30928515/random-heights-on-different-screen-widths?noredirect=1#comment49893359_30928515

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80954/discussion-between-ammarcse-and-ben-liger).

Answer (score 5):

You may use this selector:

```
$(".portfoliopod:not(.podexpanded)")
```

It will select all elements with the class `portfoliopod`, but only those that do not have the class `podexpanded`.

Comment: hmm I have implemented it on the link I gave in the description above but no joy... Is my logic maybe wrong here?