# random heights on different screen widths

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

there is a slight problem with the portfolio container divs height when it reaches certain window widths. The widths it occurs on are from 1025 to 1041 and to 768 to 784. You can see what I mean if you resize your browser window to the above heights on the live page: mrliger.com/index2.php

this div has some jquery attached to it to resize its height in this form, I suspect this is what might be causing this as opposed to a media query causing it:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
     if ($(window).width() >= 1025) {
         var cw = $(".portfoliocontainer").width() / 4;
         $('.portfoliopod:not(.podexpanded)').height(cw);
     }
     if ($(window).width() <= 1024) {
         var cw = $(".portfoliocontainer").width() / 3;
         $('.portfoliopod:not(.podexpanded)').height(cw);
     }
     if ($(window).width() <= 767) {
         var cw = $(".portfoliocontainer").width() / 2;
         $('.portfoliopod:not(.podexpanded)').height(cw);
     }
     if ($(window).width() <= 400) {
         var cw = $(".portfoliocontainer").width();
         $('.portfoliopod:not(.podexpanded)').height(cw);
     }
 });
```

Comment: can you describe what the 'problem' with the portfolio container divs height is exactly? Not to mention I see some javascript errors in my web inspector console

Comment: sure. The javascript I have in place is to ensure that the containers div height is always the same as its width. This works in most browser widths, however the div height becomes larger than its width between the mentioned window widths in my description. Hope thats clear..

Comment: I actually can see it now (don't know why I could not before). I understand that you are using javascript to accomplish this, but I highly suggest you take a CSS approach if you can. I believe this is a 'layout' issue you are experiencing that can be much more easily solved using CSS alone.

Comment: Also, the way you are managing your height to width ratio is messing up is because the ratios happen to break at those points (mathematically), unless you want to add more breakpoints in your $(window).width() if checks, it is much better to create a fluid flow leveraging CSS. I will try to come up with an example to lead you in the right way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting the width to be the same as the height

```
$(document).ready(portResize);
$(window).resize(portResize);

function portResize() {
    var cw;
    if ($(window).width() >= 1025) {
        cw = $(".portfoliocontainer").width() / 4;
    }
    if ($(window).width() <= 1024) {
        cw = $(".portfoliocontainer").width() / 3;
    }
    if ($(window).width() <= 767) {
        cw = $(".portfoliocontainer").width() / 2;
    }
    if ($(window).width() <= 400) {
        cw = $(".portfoliocontainer").width();
    }
    $('.portfoliopod:not(.podexpanded)').width(cw);
    $('.portfoliopod:not(.podexpanded)').height(cw);
}
```

Comment: @BenLiger, glad it worked. Let me know if you hit any more trouble :)